# Valores duplicados en laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, foreach

Estoy en un dilema, necesito solo obtener ciertos valores, pero omitiendo campos con ciertos valores repetidos

```
id|id_obra|imagen
1 |      1|image1.jpg
2 |      1|image12.jpg
3 |      2|image15.jpg
4 |      2|image5.jpg
5 |      3|image7.jpg
```

y necesito solo un valor de cada 'id_obra' repetido
es decir si hay dos 'id_obra' con valor 1, solo necesito el primero
lo mismo con los demas campos,

en este caso solo necesito esto

```
id|id_obra|imagen
1 |      1|image1.jpg
3 |      2|image15.jpg
5 |      3|image7.jpg
```

intente con un foreach, pero no me funciona y me muetra las dos imagenes de cada obra

```
@foreach ($imagenes as $item) 
     @if ($item->id_obra == $obra1->id)
     <img src="{{asset("storage/$item->imagen")}}"  class="card-img-top img-card2"  alt="">
     @endif
@endforeach
```

esta es mi consulta

```
$imagenes = Imagenes::distinct('id_obra')->get();
```

tambien creo que se podría evitando los valores repetidos en el foreach, pero no tengo una idea clara.

Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: No estoy respondiendo, pero has tratado de usar el comando First() ?? segun recuerdo, te permite seleccionar la primera instancia.
Seria, si mal no recuerdo `$imagenes = Imagenes::distinct('id_obra')->get()->first();`

Comment: @Excorpion tu aporte ayuda y tiene funcionalidad excepto que no es first sino get, si usas first obtendrás solo un elemento y lo demás en general será ignorado, ¿por qué no te animas a responder?

Comment: Por eso mismo dije "si mal no recuerdo", ayer no pude buscarlo para confirmarlo. De todos modos gracias por la aclaracion ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gracias por sus respuesta, todas fueron muy buenas pero lo resolví de una manera mas simple
utilizela funcion 'unique'

```
$imagen= Imagenes::distinct('id_obra')->get();
$imagenes = $imagen->unique('id_obra');
```

y de esta manera obtuve el resultado que necesitaba.
Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: No olvides marcar **tu** respuesta como aceptada cuando el sistema te lo permita

Answer (score 1):

En ese caso si quieres la primera iteracion del foreach

```
@if ($loop->first)
    This is the first iteration.
@endif
```

y si quieres la ultima iteracion seria

```
@if ($loop->last)
    This is the last iteration.
@endif
```

que en tu caso seria algo asi

```
@foreach ($imagenes as $item) 
 @if ($loop->first)
 <img src="{{asset("storage/$item->imagen")}}"  class="card-img-top img-card2"  
  alt="">
 @endif
```

@endforeach

Saludos

Comment: El OP no quiere solo el primer elemento de la iteración, quiere valores únicos por cada vez que un id se repite, dado eso no creo que esto responda la pregunta

Answer (score 1):

Puedes armar tu query de la siguiente manera:

```
DB::table('imagenes AS img1')
    ->select(
         'img1.id_obra',
         DB::raw('(SELECT img2.imagen FROM imagenes img2 WHERE img2.id_obra = img1.id_obra LIMIT 1) AS imagen')
     )
    ->groupBy('id_obra', 'imagen')
    ->get();
```

Si no lo haces de esa manera y haces un groupBy directamente, no podrás especificar qué fila, de la columna imagen, tomar para cada grupo y obtendrás el típico error:

> SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated
> column

Es por eso que debes buscarla tú mismo, dado el caso, necesitas hacer una subconsulta:

```
(SELECT img2.imagen FROM imagenes img2 WHERE img2.id_obra = img1.id_obra LIMIT 1)
```

Esto significa: Seleccionas el primer registro donde el id de la obra sea '1', '2' o '3' conforme vaya recorriendo cada fila de tu tabla.

Answer (score 1):

Si es que acaso:

- Usas o puedes cambiarte a MariaDB

Te hago la siguiente propuesta de respuesta:

- Existen columnas que de primera instancia no se pueden agrupar directo como lo son: `id` e `imagen`
- Lo que podemos hacer es una *agrupación concatenada* mediante `GROUP_CONCAT`
- Lo anterior nos generaría en cada celda el agrupamiento de N valores
- Lo que podemos hacer es que dentro del `GROUP_CONCAT` limitar la cantidad de resultados a 1 (*característica en MariaDB desde la versión [10.3.3](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/group_concat/)*)
- Finalmente agrupamos al final por la columna `id_obra`

Propuesta en SQL

```
SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(id LIMIT 1), 
        GROUP_CONCAT(imagen LIMIT 1), 
            tabla.id_obra 
FROM tabla
GROUP BY tabla.id_obra;
```

Y a nivel de Laravel hacerlo así:

```
Imagenes::selectRaw('
                        GROUP_CONCAT(id LIMIT 1) AS id, 
                        GROUP_CONCAT(imagen LIMIT 1) AS imagen,
                        id_obra
                    ')
        ->groupBy('id_obra')
        ->get();
```